# Problemas no Menu Dropdown do Bootstrap em telas SM

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Estou com um problema com um menu `dropdown` que eu fiz utilizando *Bootstrap*.

O Problema é o seguinte, o menu funcionou perfeitamente para dispositivos tamanho *XS*. Porém, ele não funciona em dispositivos tamanho *SM* (Que era o que eu queria. Gostaria que o menu fosse utilizado também em Tablets).

Já pesquisei em vários fóruns e ainda não consegui achar uma resposta. 
Vou deixar o código aqui abaixo, para saber se vocês podem me ajudar. 
Desde já, agradeço a atenção.

```
<!------------ MENU MÓVEL -------------->

                <nav class="navbar navbar-default hidden-md hidden-lg navbar-fixed-top " id="nav-movel">


                <!--------- DIV DAS REDES SOCIAIS ----------->

                    <div class="row visible-xs visible-sm" id="cabecalho-superior-movel">

                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="cabecalho-superior-acerto">
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jcacontadores/" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesFace.png"></a>
                            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jcacontadores/" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesInsta.png"></a>
                            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jca-contadores-406/" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesLink.png"></a>
                            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLb6KnKGdjKh-usDWdZ93yg?view_as=subscriber" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesYouTube.png"></a>
                            <a href="https://encurtador.com.br/gOPZ6" target="_blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/icone-zap.png"></a>
                            <a href="mailto:contato@jcacontadores.com.br"><img src="_imagens/icones/icone-email.png"></a>
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contato"><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Fale com um Especialista</button></a>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <section class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">

                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#movelmenu" arial-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>


                                <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="_imagens/logo-216x93.png" class="logo-menu-movel">
                                </a>

                        </div>


                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="movelmenu">

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="ul-movel">
                                <li class="" id="li-menu-movel"><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
                                <li class="" role="presentation" class="dropdown" id="li-menu-movel">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                      SOBRE<span class="caret"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                      <li class="li-submenu-movel" id="li-submenu-movel"><a href="quemsomos.php" target="blank">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
                                    </ul>

                                </li>
                                <li class="li-menu-movel" id="li-menu-movel"><a href="#">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown li-menu-movel" id="li-menu-movel">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                      CARREIRAS<span class="caret"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                      <li id="li-submenu-movel" ><a href="contato-despertando.php" target="blank">PROGRAMA DESPERTANDO TALENTOS</a></li>
                                      <li class="li-submenu-movel" id="li-submenu-movel" ><a href="contato-profissionais.php" target="blank">PROGRAMA PROFISSIONAIS EXPERIENTE</a></li>
                                    </ul>

                                </li>
                                <li id="li-menu-movel"><a href="https://jcasistemas.info/">BLOG</a></li>
                                <li id="li-menu-movel"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contato">CONTATO</a></li>
                                <li id="li-menu-movel"><a href="location.htm">ÁREA DO CLIENTE</a></li>

                            </ul>


                        </div>
                    </section>
                </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo seu problema é que vc está usando o código de uma `navbar` do **Bootstrap 3** mas com os CSS e JS do **Bootstrap 4**. ***(Se vc pegou essa `navabar` pronta em algum site certifique-se de qual foi a versão usada para ela funcionar corretamente.)***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que quando eu usei seu código, podem indexando as aquivos da **Versão 3 do Bootstrap ela funcionou** perfeitamente! Mas se vc indexar os arquivos do **Bootstrap 4 ela vai da pau** mesmo...

---

**EDIT**

Primeiro remova as classes `hidden-md hidden-lg`, pois com elas a navbar vai sumir em telas maiores que `992px` Depois para a Navbar "collapsar" no toggle menu aos 992px vc deve incluir no seu CSS as linhas de que utilizei abaixo, assim ele vai ativer o toggle menu na resolução que vc deseja.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
 }
 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  line-height: 20px;
 }
 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
 }
 .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        /*margin: 7.5px -15px;*/
  margin: 7.5px 50px 7.5px -15px
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .navbar-text {
        float: none;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
    /* since 3.1.0 */
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
        display: block!important;
    }
    .collapsing {
        overflow: hidden!important;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top hidden-md hidden-lg" id="nav-movel">


<!--------- DIV DAS REDES SOCIAIS ----------->

    <div class="row visible-xs visible-sm" id="cabecalho-superior-movel">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="cabecalho-superior-acerto">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jcacontadores/" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesFace.png"></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jcacontadores/" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesInsta.png"></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jca-contadores-406/" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesLink.png"></a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLb6KnKGdjKh-usDWdZ93yg?view_as=subscriber" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesYouTube.png"></a>
            <a href="https://encurtador.com.br/gOPZ6" target="_blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/icone-zap.png"></a>
            <a href="mailto:contato@jcacontadores.com.br"><img src="_imagens/icones/icone-email.png"></a>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contato"><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Fale com um Especialista</button></a>
        </div>

    </div>

    
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#movelmenu" arial-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>


                <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand" target="_blank">
                    <img src="_imagens/logo-216x93.png" class="logo-menu-movel">
                </a>

        </div>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="movelmenu" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="ul-movel">
                <li class="" id="li-menu-movel"><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="" role="presentation" class="dropdown" id="li-menu-movel">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        SOBRE<span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="li-submenu-movel" id="li-submenu-movel"><a href="quemsomos.php" target="blank">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li class="li-menu-movel" id="li-menu-movel"><a href="#">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown li-menu-movel" id="li-menu-movel">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        CARREIRAS<span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li id="li-submenu-movel" ><a href="contato-despertando.php" target="blank">PROGRAMA DESPERTANDO TALENTOS</a></li>
                        <li class="li-submenu-movel" id="li-submenu-movel" ><a href="contato-profissionais.php" target="blank">PROGRAMA PROFISSIONAIS EXPERIENTE</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li id="li-menu-movel"><a href="https://jcasistemas.info/">BLOG</a></li>
                <li id="li-menu-movel"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contato">CONTATO</a></li>
                <li id="li-menu-movel"><a href="location.htm">ÁREA DO CLIENTE</a></li>

            </ul>


        </div>
    
</nav>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olá, amigo hugocsl. Obrigado pelo retorno. Como eu havia dito, o meu menu está funcionando perfeitamente no tamanho "XS" (Mobile), o problema é que ele não está funcionando no tamanho "SM" (Tablet), e é esse tamanho que eu gostaria que ele funcionasse. No seu exemplo, ele está funcionando perfeitamente, entretanto, você está utilizando width de 722px (Tamanho XS). Nesse tamanho de XS o meu também funciona. O meu problema é que não funciona no tamanho "SM" (Que é de 768px até 992px). Se puder me dar uma solução de como fazer o menu funcionar em outros tamanhos além do "XS", eu ficaria grato.

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson é que vc tinha colocado a tag [Bootstrap-4] na sua pergunta, ai ficou confuso. Mas agora entendi o que vc queria. Leia o **EDIT** que fiz na resposta que vc vai ver que agora aos 992px o menu collapsa no toggle menu

Comment: Na primeira vista, deu tudo certo no menu. Porém, ao olhar melhor, ele veio meio que com os <li>, digo os submenus, meio que bugados e com uns paddings laterais.

Comment: Eu gostaria que esse Menu ficasse visivel em XS e SM e ficasse Hidden nos tamanhos MD e LG. Estou quebrando a cabeça pra fazer isso no bootstrap.

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson cara acabei de fazer uma atualização geral, agora ele funciona como o esperado, um dos problemas com o bug que vc falou é pq vc tinha colocado uma Section com classe .container dentro da navbar, isso quebrou o layout. E agora as LI expandem corretamente. Além diso coloquei a classe Hidden devolta na navbar, mas dessa forma em telas maiores que 992px a navbar some completamente, então em telas maiores que 992px não tem mais menu visível.. Testa ai pra ver se ficou no jeito e me fala

Comment: Fala ai, meu mago. Agora deu tudo certinho. Só tive que ajustar uns paddings e uns margins do seu css. Mas foi coisa mínima. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Grande abraço !

Comment: Uma última pergunta. Por que eu só consigo utilizar esse código CSS na área <style> da página e não em um arquivo CSS externo que eu chamo na página ? Pois assim eu terei que criar esse código CSS em todas as páginas do site...

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson é que o Bootstrap tem uma Hierarquia de Classes muito forte, vc pode até colocar em um arquivo .CSS separado, mas pode ser que vc precise usar `!important` nas propriedades. Outro detalhe é que esse .CSS deve vir depois, abaixo do .CSS do Bootstrap ok! Faz o teste colocando dessa forma e me fala. Se vc achar que a pergunta foi respondida lembre-se de marca-la como aceita nesse ícone **✔** ao lado das setinha, assim sua pergunta não fica pendente no site. E se tiver mais algum problema é só me dar um toque

Comment: Eu agradeço muito pelas dicas. Eu estou fazendo um site para a empresa em que faço estágio. Estou usando html,css,javascript, bootstrap, jquery e um mínimo de php. Gostaria de saber se vc poderia dar uma olhada no site, mesmo que superficialmente, e me dar umas dicas de melhorias. Pode ser melhorias de layout, de SEO... Goataria de deixar o site leve, bonito e funcional. O site é thiagopetherson.tech . Agradeço muito a paciência. Abraço-

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson cara na verdade eu sou apenas um designer rss, não tenho todo esse conhecimento para te dar essa "consultoria", Mas reparei que o site não tem ALT em todas as imagens, isso não é bom para SEO ou Acessibilidade. Vc pode Condensar todos os .CSS em um só na versão que vai para ser publicada no servidor isso vai ajudar o site a carregar mais rápido. Eu deixaria o texto dos Serviços centralizado para telas mobile. E se vc achar que essa pergunta está resolvida marque como aceita no ícone **✔** ao lado das setinhas no alto a esquerda da minha resposta. []´s